# Swift AppDelegate to Pass Data between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I want to have like centralized class. Set data from one view controller and access the data from another view controller.

Here is what I did. But it is not working.

First the class:

```
class User {
  var userName: String? = ""
}
```

AppDelegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var user: User?
.....
```

Finally the viewController

```
let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
 delegate.user?.userName = "abcd"
 print(delegate.user?.userName)
```

It always returns nil object

Any help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You never assign a value to `user`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you don't assign a value to the user , so Replace

```
var user: User?
```

With

```
var user = User()
```

BTW your way is fit for a singleton like

```
class Service {
  static let shared = Service()
  var user = User()
}
```

Access for anywhere

```
Service.shared.user.userName = "----"
```

---

It could also be

```
var user: User?
```

but you should know where in your app flow it's nil/not ( first assign init it ) , such as assign it a value from an asynchronous methods , then other subsequent accesses will have a value , when logout set it to nil again ....etc

Answer (score 1):

Put the following lines in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` methods.

```
 user = User()
 user?.userName = "abcd"
```